# React hook - dispatch an async await action in another file

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

For example, I have a method with would dispatch an action like

```
// index.js
export default class PageNavigation {
    export async switchPage(pageId) {
      return async (dispatch) => {
          await dispatch(selectPage({ pageId }));
          await dispatch(changeTitle({ pageId }));
          //... more dispatch
    };
    function selectPage(id) {
       return async (dispatch, getState) => {
         //await some complex logic involve some other dispatch
       }
    };
    function changeTitle(id) {
       return async (dispatch, getState) => {
         //await some complex logic involve some other dispatch
       }
    };
}
```

Now I have a react hook component that uses `useDispatch()` hook which I want to call the `switchPage` method above using `dispatch` hook, I have tried following way but none of them works:

```
const PageManagement = (props) => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   // Try 1: the 'dispatch' inside switchPage didn't get fired, seems the dispatch here is undefined?
   await switchPage('640');
   // Try 2: Global Unhandled Promise Rejection Error: Actions must be plain objects. 
   // Use custom middleware for async actions.
   dispatch(switchPage('640'));
}
```

What would be the correct way for implement above scenario? I know below would work by directly calling the action using `dispatch` but that's not what I am looking for, because once there is more actions, it seems each action need to be dispatched one by one?

```
await dispatch(selectPage('640'));
await dispatch(changeTitle('640'));
// ... keep calling other dispatch in component?
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should provide `dispatch` as an argument:

```
export async switchPage(dispatch, pageId) {
          await dispatch(selectPage({ pageId }));
          await dispatch(changeTitle({ pageId }));
    };
```

And then call it this way in your component:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
await switchPage(dispatch, '640');
```